# Wso2 Microservices (MSF4j) and Data Analysis Server (DAS) integration issue

Tags: wso2, wso2-das, msf4j, wso2-msf4j

I was trying to run sample            https://github.com/wso2/msf4j/tree/master/samples/metrics-httpmon/metrics-httpmon-fatjar with DAS.

My environment is Windows so, I just copied carbon apps and module zips to appropriate directories as explained in 
    https://github.com/wso2/msf4j/blob/master/analytics/das-setup/setup.sh

After loading UI on http://127.0.0.1:9763/monitoring/ I can see following errors on browsers JS console.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)
>   http://127.0.0.1:9763/monitoring/api/as-data.jag?action=response
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)
>   http://127.0.0.1:9763/monitoring/api/as-data.jag?action=request Failed
>   to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal
>   Server Error)
>   http://127.0.0.1:9763/monitoring/api/as-data.jag?action=error Failed
>   to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal
>   Server Error)

Ans following errors on DAS console. Although I can see monitoring UI, it will not show relevant information for requests (for microservice). Could someone help me to resolve this issue?

> [2016-05-19 14:04:36,103] ERROR
>   {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager} - 
>   org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: u
>   (/monitoring/api/modules/info-box-stat.js#222)
>   org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException:
>   org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: u
>   (/monitoring/api/modules/info-box-stat.js#222)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:571)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:587)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:507)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doGet(JaggeryServlet.java:24)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: u
>   (/monitoring/api/modules/info-box-stat.js#222)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3687)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3665)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJSON.parse(NativeJSON.java:112)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJSON.execIdCall(NativeJSON.java:88)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.monitoring.api.modules.c2._c_getInfoBoxErrorStat_6(/monitoring/api/modules/info-box-stat.js:222)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.monitoring.api.modules.c2.call(/monitoring/api/modules/info-box-stat.js)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.monitoring.api.c0._c_getInfoBoxErrorStat_13(/monitoring/api/as-data.jag:164)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.monitoring.api.c0.call(/monitoring/api/as-data.jag)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.monitoring.api.c0._c_script_0(/monitoring/api/as-data.jag:184)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.monitoring.api.c0.call(/monitoring/api/as-data.jag)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.monitoring.api.c0.call(/monitoring/api/as-data.jag)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.monitoring.api.c0.exec(/monitoring/api/as-data.jag)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
>           ... 39 more [2016-05-19 14:04:36,047] ERROR {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager} - 
>   org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: u
>   (/monitoring/api/modules/app-list.js#43)
>   org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException:
>   org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: u
>   (/monitoring/api/modules/app-list.js#43)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:571)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:587)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:507)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doGet(JaggeryServlet.java:24)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: u
>   (/monitoring/api/modules/app-list.js#43)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3687)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3665)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJSON.parse(NativeJSON.java:112)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJSON.execIdCall(NativeJSON.java:88)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.monitoring.api.modules.c4._c_getPastStat_1(/monitoring/api/modules/app-list.js:43)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.monitoring.api.modules.c4.call(/monitoring/api/modules/app-list.js)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.monitoring.api.modules.c4._c_getAppsStat_4(/monitoring/api/modules/app-list.js:102)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.monitoring.api.modules.c4.call(/monitoring/api/modules/app-list.js)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.monitoring.api.c0._c_getAppsStat_3(/monitoring/api/as-data.jag:82)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.monitoring.api.c0.call(/monitoring/api/as-data.jag)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.monitoring.api.c0._c_script_0(/monitoring/api/as-data.jag:184)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.monitoring.api.c0.call(/monitoring/api/as-data.jag)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.monitoring.api.c0.call(/monitoring/api/as-data.jag)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.monitoring.api.c0.exec(/monitoring/api/as-data.jag)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
>           ... 39 more [2016-05-19 14:04:36,906] ERROR {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager} - 
>   org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: u
>   (/monitoring/api/modules/time-varying-stat.js#47)
>   org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException:
>   org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: u
>   (/monitoring/api/modules/time-varying-stat.js#47)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:571)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:587)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:507)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doGet(JaggeryServlet.java:24)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: u
>   (/monitoring/api/modules/time-varying-stat.js#47)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3687)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3665)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJSON.parse(NativeJSON.java:112)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJSON.execIdCall(NativeJSON.java:88)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.monitoring.api.modules.c3._c_getTimeVaryingStat_2(/monitoring/api/modules/time-varying-stat.js:47)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.monitoring.api.modules.c3.call(/monitoring/api/modules/time-varying-stat.js)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.monitoring.api.c0._c_getRequestStat_7(/monitoring/api/as-data.jag:116)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.monitoring.api.c0.call(/monitoring/api/as-data.jag)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.monitoring.api.c0._c_script_0(/monitoring/api/as-data.jag:184)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.monitoring.api.c0.call(/monitoring/api/as-data.jag)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.monitoring.api.c0.call(/monitoring/api/as-data.jag)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.monitoring.api.c0.exec(/monitoring/api/as-data.jag)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
>           ... 39 more [2016-05-19 14:04:36,974] ERROR {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager} - 
>   org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: u
>   (/monitoring/api/modules/time-varying-stat.js#47)
>   org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException:
>   org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: u
>   (/monitoring/api/modules/time-varying-stat.js#47)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:571)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:587)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:507)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doGet(JaggeryServlet.java:24)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: u
>   (/monitoring/api/modules/time-varying-stat.js#47)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3687)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3665)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJSON.parse(NativeJSON.java:112)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJSON.execIdCall(NativeJSON.java:88)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.monitoring.api.modules.c3._c_getTimeVaryingStat_2(/monitoring/api/modules/time-varying-stat.js:47)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.monitoring.api.modules.c3.call(/monitoring/api/modules/time-varying-stat.js)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.monitoring.api.c0._c_getResponseStat_8(/monitoring/api/as-data.jag:124)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.monitoring.api.c0.call(/monitoring/api/as-data.jag)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.monitoring.api.c0._c_script_0(/monitoring/api/as-data.jag:184)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.monitoring.api.c0.call(/monitoring/api/as-data.jag)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.monitoring.api.c0.call(/monitoring/api/as-data.jag)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.monitoring.api.c0.exec(/monitoring/api/as-data.jag)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
>           ... 39 more [2016-05-19 14:04:36,927] ERROR {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager} - 
>   org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: u
>   (/monitoring/api/modules/time-varying-stat.js#47)
>   org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException:
>   org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: u
>   (/monitoring/api/modules/time-varying-stat.js#47)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:571)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:587)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:507)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doGet(JaggeryServlet.java:24)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)

Comment: is this browser issue? I checked with Chrome and FF latest versions

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue in the HTTP Monitoring Application. If there is no data in Data Analytics Server and if you open the HTTP Monitoring Application, there will be some errors in the log.

Could you please try manually executing the script for batch analytics.

For more information see [MSF4J Analytics README](https://github.com/wso2/msf4j/tree/master/analytics#for-advanced-users) and [how to execute scripts in WSO2 DAS](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS301/Scheduling+Batch+Analytics+Scripts#SchedulingBatchAnalyticsScripts-Executingascript)

After running the script, please check the HTTP Monitoring Application and see whether you can see data.